# Функция memcpy на Java

Tags: java, memory

Есть ли аналог `memcpy` на Java?

Нужно для создания копии экземпляра класса:

```
myClass a = new myClass();  
/*  
* ... действия над a  
*/
myClass b;
b = a;  // b ссылается на a
//Нужно создать копию класса a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = a.clone();
```

Comment: Учтите, что это не является аналогом в буквальном смысле. В чистом виде memcpy для копирования экземпляров класса нет.

Comment: Ознакомился с этим методом. Я правильно понял, если memcpy копирует всю указанную область памяти, то `.clone()` копирует только поля класса?  
Если полями класса являются другие классы, они тоже должны унаследоваться из `Clonable`?

Comment: Нет. Глубокое клонирование не выполняется по умолчанию. Просто копируются ссылки.

Comment: И как же сделать клонирование всех объектов внутри класса, всех подобъектов и под-под-под-под..... объектов?

Comment: Если полями класса являются ссылки на изменяемые (не immutable) объекты, то их клонирование и присвоение полям целевого объекта нужно произвести вручную - соответственно, они тоже должны реализовывать `Cloneable`.

Comment: А есть красивый способ, не вручную?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/cloning/   <br/>
Хотя вообще на тему очень много разговоров. Ищите по ключевым словам "Java deep clone"

Comment: ОУ! Круто! Хороший ответ, @cy6erGn0m !

Comment: То, что я искал, хотя для моей задачи и clone() можно использовать.  
Что скажете о скорости выполнения clone() и deepClone()?

Comment: Лучше бы не делать этого. Вообще, на практике, я не помню, как много лет прошло с тех пор, как мне в последний раз понадобился clone или тем более deep clone. Кстати, я видел где-то ещё этот deepClone.. то ли в апачевских либах, то ли ещё где-то.. не припомню точно.

Comment: Предлагаете собственноручно написать функцию копирования?

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, что помимо вариаций с реализациями `deep copy`, возможны также следующие варианты:

*Использование `copyOf` для примитивных типов `(с версии 1.6)`:*

```
byte[] src = {1, 2, 3, 4};
byte[] dst = Arrays.copyOf(src, src.length);
```

---

*Сериализация-десериализация объектов, соптимизированная с учетом того, что мы всего лищь хотим скопировать фрагмент памяти:*

[См. здесь.](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скопировать класс - есть разные способы. Сложность в том, что у тебя может быть ссылка на базовый класс, в то время, как реальный экземпляр является дочерним классом.

Например есть базовый класс Animal и дочерние: Cat(Animal) и Dog(Animal).

`Animal a1 = new Cat();`
тебе надо сделать что-то типа :
`Animal a2 = copy(a);`

Вот тут начинается самое интересное. Есть несколько вариантов

Самый тупой вариант можно сделать так :

```
if(a1 insfanceof Cat){
  a2 = new Cat();
  a2.field = a1.field;
}
if(a1 insfanceof Dog){
  a2 = new Dog();
  a2.field = a1.field;
}
```

Но тогда нарушается принцип SOLID. Ты не должен знать о конкретной реализации, а должен работать с абстракцией.

Второй способ - сделать Clonable. Eго надо реализовавать в каждом подклассе. Получается, что тебе тоже надо в каждый подкласс спускаться и что-то там реализовывать. Получается довольно длинно.

```
public class Test {
            public static class Animal implements Cloneable{
                public Animal clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                    return (Animal) super.clone();
                }
            }

            public static class Cat extends Animal{
                public Cat clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                    return (Cat) super.clone();
                }
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                Animal a1 = new Cat();
                Animal a2 = a1.clone();
                System.out.println(a1);
                System.out.println(a2);
            }
}
```

Третий вариант - это через рефлексию. 
Четвертый вариант - через сериализацию-десериализацию. 
Пятый вариант -- взять исходники openJDK и сделать свою джаву с memcpy.